# Android - how to set background image which path is in array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm having the following array:

```
final String[][] dataArr = {
        {"R.drawable.bengaltiger", "bengaltiger"},
        {"R.drawable.cat", "cat"},
        {"R.drawable.chimp", "chimp"},
        {"R.drawable.eagle", "eagle"},
        {"R.drawable.frog", "frog"},
        {"R.drawable.lamb", "lamb"},
        {"R.drawable.wolf", "wolf"},
};
```

From this one I'm trying to play a sound and use a image as background for the button:

```
final Button guessRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butRight);
guessRight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bengaltiger);
```

It's not possible to set the background image with an image which uri is in the array because the function "setBackgroundResource" is expecting an int or an URI where I'm having a string.

MY QUESTION WOULD BE HOW TO TRANSFORM THE STRING INTO URI SO i CAN USE THE PATH FROM THE ARRAY WITHIN THE "setBackgroundResource" FUNCTION?

Is my approach correct? or should I use another way to store my data or handle it in different way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

1. You seem to want to use a String to hold the symbol name of each of your IDs. You yourself pointed out that this won't work.
2. You are storing these in a 2-dimensional String array, which is the wrong data structure.

Instead, you will want to store these in a [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html).

```
Map<Integer, String> imageMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>
// Put the other ones here.
imageMap.put(R.drawable.bengalTiger, "bengaltiger");
.
.
.

// Later on, use them like this:
for(Integer id : imageMap.keyset()) {
  String name = imageMap.get(id);
  // You can now use "id" and "name" in whatever UI elements you want.
}
```

Also, if you are storing an arbitrary number of IDs and names in your list, then why are you getting the view to put them into from a layout? It seems you would want to create them programmatically, otherwise why not just set this all up in the XML layout to begin with?